# How to get rid of horizontal scroll bar in diagonal full screen layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design

How do I get rid of the overflow horizontal scroll bar? I have two diagonal shapes using CSS3. I've tried everything for the right side but nothing works. I even put overflow: hidden.

Is there a way I can adjust the div .right so it's not poking out causing the horizontal scroll bar?

I'm sure it's a noob mistake but I need another set of eyes.

```css
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.left{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #ff9a00;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: -50%;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dual-screen">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you are apply the overflow:hidden to the wrong element, try apply the overflow rule to the div with the class="row". Overflow should be applied to the container that you want to hide child from overflowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're looking for is to add **[`overflow-x: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)** to one of your containing elements.
This element must be at least one level **up** from `.dual-screen`.

`overflow-x` controls the overflow **horizontally**.
Setting it to `hidden` hides this overflow, and thus the scrollbar isn't visible.

In the following example, I've added it to `<body>`:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.left {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ff9a00;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: -50%;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dual-screen">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for responding! Putting overflow-x: hidden; on the body fixes it but I was hoping I could adjust .right div class to prevent it from poking out. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The general concept of 'angled' elements like this is to allow them to poke out, and then use `overflow: hidden` on a parent in order to mask it.

Comment: Darn. Okay that makes sense. Thank you for pointing that out. I learned something.